# R: Concatenate data frame column name with a number

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have this simple code that creates a matrix and a data frame:

```
   mat=matrix(rnorm(40*5), ncol=5)
   df=as.data.frame(mat)
   df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", V1:V5)
```

Here is the head(df) created by mat:

```
           V1          V2          V3          V4          V5
1   0.97111725  0.12937942 -0.89643594 -0.30144874  0.10405400
2   0.68372321 -0.08049954 -0.52891953 -0.56752185 -1.04425728
3   1.04553733  0.24499356  0.25919424 -1.51280159  0.70952009
4   0.16433896 -0.46727565 -0.22030923  1.18732203  0.17529333
5  -1.73732058  0.04977374  1.54042252 -1.27585563 -1.05846972
6   0.35953274  3.09224985 -1.24524965 -0.67492542 -0.68065365
```

I then create another data frame `df2` where I gather the values onto two columns `x` and `y`.

```
df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", V1:V5)
```

When I get new datasets where the matrix has a different number of columns, I have to change the value of the columns of `df2` to another number.

**Example**: here I use `V5` because I have 5 columns: `df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", V1:V5)` so now If I get a new matrix with 40 columns I have to change that manually to `V20`:  `df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", V1:V20)`.

Is there any way to write it like: `df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", V1:V+ncol(mat)`

Comment: You are gathering all columns, so you can leave that argument blank... `tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y")` ?

Comment: This appears to work: `df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", "V1":"V5")`. You can expand it to simply put in the first column you want as a character and then the last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can use paste.

```
df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x" ,"y", V1:paste0("V", ncol(mat)))
```

Of course you're using all the columns so you don't need to specify the names. But in cases where you truly want to reference variable column names, this is how I go about it.

Alternatively, if you want to use all columns starting with "V", you could do

```
df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", dplyr::starts_with("V"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It also looks like you can simply pass the columns as characters like:

```
df3 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", names(df)[1]:names(df)[5])
```

Or as you specifically state in your example to go from `V1:V+ncol(df)` you can do:

```
df3 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", "V1":tail(names(df),1))
```

And then comparing to your result:

```
identical(df2,df3)
#[1] TRUE
```

This might be nice because it provides the flexibility to programmatically choose any range of columns you want compared to the option where you exclude any columns and it automatically gathers all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Simple column index works with `gather` as well.

> The documentation of `gather` reads for `...` arguments as:
>
> A selection of columns. If empty, all variables are selected. You can 
>   supply bare variable names,  supply bare variable names,
>   select all variables between x and z with x:z, exclude y with -y. For
>   more options, see the dplyr::select() documentation.

```
mat=matrix(rnorm(40*5), ncol=5)
df=as.data.frame(mat)

df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", 1:5)

#OR
df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y", V1:V5)

#OR
df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x", "y")  #all columns 


head(df2)
# x          y
# 1 V1 -0.7403657
# 2 V1 -0.7501310
# 3 V1  2.0371748
# 4 V1 -1.2647994
# 5 V1  1.3464162
# 6 V1 -1.8981365

tail(df2)
# x          y
# 195 V5 -2.2739219
# 196 V5 -0.8606414
# 197 V5 -0.8102747
# 198 V5  0.6362617
# 199 V5  0.9962820
# 200 V5  1.6503455
```