# Concatenate dataframe column name with string for referencing

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several similarly named columns in a dataframe with a number differentiating between them. I'm trying to break the data into smaller chunks. My code looks something like this:

```
num <- c(5,10,15,20,30,40,50,60, 100)    
a <- data.frame(df$T5, df$Vf5, df$Im5)
b <- data.frame(df$T10, df$Vf10, df$Im10)
c <- data.frame(df$T15, df$Vf15, df$Im15)
```

I don't want write out the numbers manually. I tried using `paste0("out$T",5)` and `as.name()` with it but it didn't seem to work.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240338/r-concatenate-data-frame-column-name-with-a-number) but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share some of your data? You can do `dput(head(df))` into the console, then paste the results into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `lapply(letters, function(.x) df[as.vector(outer(.x, num, FUN = paste0))])`
where `letters = c('T', 'Vf', 'Im')`

See [How to cross-paste all combinations of two vectors (each-to-each)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154318/how-to-cross-paste-all-combinations-of-two-vectors-each-to-each)